# Arduino TCP Server with Java Client

Tags: java, tcp, arduino, server

I have been trying to get my Arduino Uno with an Ethernet shield to work as a TCP server to connect to with a java client. The java client sees that the port is in use but the Arduino server does not see the java client, however the Arduino server does see a web browser as a client when I type in the IP and port number. I have tried the Arduino server code from the Arduino website and had no luck with it either.

Arduino Server Code:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 30);
byte mac[] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF};

EthernetServer server = EthernetServer(1234);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  delay(1000);

  server.begin();

  Serial.println("Waiting for client...");

}

void loop() {

  EthernetClient client = server.available();

  if(client == true){

    Serial.println("Connected");

  }

}
```

Java Client Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPClient {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      try {

         Socket skt = new Socket("192.168.0.30", 1234);

         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));

         System.out.print("Received string: '");

         while (!in.ready()) {}

         System.out.println(in.readLine()); // Read one line and output it

         System.out.print("'\n");
         in.close();

      }catch(Exception e) {

         System.out.print("Connection Failed\n");
         e.printStackTrace();

      }

   }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try to add `server.write("Hello\n");` to see if the java receives it.

Comment: Thanks @Ôrel java did receive the message, but the server did not recognize the connection or receive a message from java when I added `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream());out.println("Message Received!");`

Comment: Seems to be an java issue. You can try to use `nc` or `netcat` as client and server to understand where is the problem. You server succes to write on socket and your client reads the message, you are closed to have something working.

Comment: Maybe a flush() on the stream _might_ help. Or the autoflush constructor new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true)...

Comment: And  as with any networking issue, [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is your friend...

Comment: @Ôrel I have tried an other TCP client (one from google play store) and the server still did not see that it was connected.